# Python Bokeh: Slider callback in ColumnDataSource not update

Tags: python, python-requests, bokeh

I having a problem with the callback, I got everything worked expect the part when the graph doesn't update even thou the array is updated when I change the slider.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure

data = {'x_values': [0,0,2,2,4,4],
        'y_values': [10,0,0,5,5,10]} #Seting up data

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data) # Map plot

plot = figure(title="Step Well",
              tools="save,wheel_zoom")

plot.line('x_values', 'y_values',source=source)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    Step = StepHeight.value

    x = [0,0,2,2,4,4]
    y = [10,0,0,Step,Step,10]
    source.data = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y))
    source.on_change('value', update_data)

StepHeight = Slider(title="Step Height", 
                    value=4.0, 
                    start=2.0, end=6.0, step=0.2)
# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(StepHeight)

layout = row(inputs, plot)

curdoc().title = "Sliders"
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to make source.data a column data source but source should be the column data source. Source.data is just a dictionary. I changed some things in your code and it should work fine now.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure

data = {'x_values': [0,0,2,2,4,4],
        'y_values': [10,0,0,5,5,10]} #Seting up data

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data) # Map plot

plot = figure(title="Step Well",
              tools="save,wheel_zoom")

plot.line('x_values', 'y_values',source=source)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    y = [10,0,0,new,new,10]
    source.data['y_values'] = y

StepHeight = Slider(title="Step Height", 
                    value=4.0, 
                    start=2.0, end=6.0, step=0.2)

StepHeight.on_change('value', update_data)

# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(StepHeight)

layout = row(inputs, plot)

curdoc().title = "Sliders"
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```